# What if my Django server receives more traffic than I can afford?

Tags: django, server, traffic

Please let me know in order what happens when there are more users.

If the server crashes, will it automatically recover if the traffic drops again?

Env: one `server`, use `nginx-gunicorn`. but no use auto-healing service.(`beanstalk, k8s, ...`)
Traffic: I don't know. but i assume server can cover 10 visitors, and there are 100 visitors

I don't want to cover much users. but i just want to know what will happen when more visitor than server available.

Comment: This is all highly dependent on your deployment setup. Are you running your application using something like gunicorn or uWSGI? Are you running that process using a supervisor like systemd? Are you proxying traffic to your WSGI app through something like NGINX or Apache? There are way too many variables in play to provide a good answer without a lot of clarification.

Comment: @ChathanDriehuys I don't want to cover much users. but i just want to know what will happen when more visitor than server available.

Comment: AFAIK you are using http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/design.html#sync-workers if all your workers are busy, gunicorn will spawn a new one, if there is not enough RAM to allocate a new worker nginx will response 503. If there is enough and worker was spawned, it will give nginx the response and die to keep your --workers option number. Also to bemore confident on production you can measure the loads via Apache Jmeter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the server is on site and you own it and you don't mind bringing it to a crawl, then just test it yourself. You can do this with "Apache Benchmark" (usually just "ab" on linux command line). With ab you can hit a server with lots of concurrent requests and get a report about how you did. You could send GET, POST, etc. Try hitting one you consider one of your more resource intensive endpoints, using gradually more severe test scenarios.

You could also run your site in your own browser at the same time, and see for yourself exactly what it will look like when the server is heavily loaded.

On the other hand, if your site is *running on shared hardware*, you should be a bit  more careful. If you conduct a severe load test against shared hosting, you could certainly appear to them to be an attacker. They might not be happy.  But, if you are careful not to go overboard, ab can still be useful to you by making it simple to simulate 10 or 20 or 200 users at one time and get a nice report about the general experience of all of them (e.g. average response time, number of requests failed, etc.)

TLDR: use Apache Benchmark ("ab") to simulate lots of load. Don't overdo it if using shared hosting.

Finally, if you are concerned and want to add a bit of hardware protection to your situation, then consider getting a Cloudflare account and put your site behind that. It will do caching for you and can also provide throttling and other load control features. It is free for some features and inexpensive for others.

Comment: I know that site slow, and show 5xx error when many traffics. but i wonder what happen inside server.

Answer (score 0):

Question is a bit abstract, can you add more details like,

- Django is running multiple instances or one? if multiple, is there  load-balancer
  (ngnix like)?
- How much traffic?
- What do you mean by crash? If it is
  'traceback' then depends on where and how it is handled, if you mean
  back-end is taking much time to process solution is to run them in
  different processes.

If your intention is to **rate-limit** the requests coming to API, then it's called throttling, you can limit them using various methods mentioned here:
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/throttling/